# Should my form have wp_nonce_field() in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, plugins

I am doing a custom calculator in wordpress. Should my form have wp_nonce_field()?

Comment: If you're not going to store the resulting data in a database or perform an operation that might include sensitive data I don't see a reason why you would need to.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to add wp_nonce for security purpose especially for wordpress forms. But still captcha does the same.